# MFC Radio buttons changing the button names dynamically

Tags: forms, mfc, radio-button

I have created a MFC form with 4 radio buttons, with names A, B, X,Y on the form,

Now I want the form to display the names X, Y when I select the button A

and when I select the button B, I want the names of X, Y to change to M, N

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the text on radiobutton the way you change the on any other control, using SetWindowText();

In order to handle the events of "selecting" the radiobuttons, add a handler for BN_CLICKED notification message. I recommend you use the same handler for all your four radiobuttons. Then, inside the function write this small code:

```
// assumptions:
// there are four radiobuttons: IDC_RADIOA, IDC_RADIOB, IDC_RADIOX, IDC_RADIOY
// The message map
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_RADIOA, OnRadio)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_RADIOB, OnRadio)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_RADIOX, OnRadio)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_RADIOY, OnRadio)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// a common handler for all four radiobuttons
void CMyDlg::OnRadio()
{
  switch(GetCheckedRadioButton(IDC_RADIOA, IDC_RADIOY))
  {
  case IDC_RADIOA:
     SetDlgItemText(IDC_RADIOX, _T("X"));
     SetDlgItemText(IDC_RADIOY, _T("Y"));
     break;
  case IDC_RADIOB:
     SetDlgItemText(IDC_RADIOX, _T("M"));
     SetDlgItemText(IDC_RADIOY, _T("N"));
     break;
  default:
     // you have not specified what to do when you select radio X and Y, so specify it here
     break;
  }
}
```